# Open dialers from my application

Tags: android, skype

Is there a way to activate Skype / some SIP clients / Viberer and other directly from my application for a specific phone number or contact?
I'm writing a small utility that we'll need to dial directly after selecting a contact.
What I want to do is give the user the option to dial using GSM - that not a problem, but also Skype and other VOIP clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) Intent to achieve what you need.

Comment: using the  ACTION_DIAL will open the gsm dialer, I want to have option to open directly the skype and other voip clients

Comment: If you have other applications installed it will not open the GSM dialer but will give a chooser option which should include Skype and other applications.